# Twilio Video using ASP.Net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, twilio

How can I use twilio video in asp.net WebForms? Is it mandatory to have node.js to use the client js library? I created token on backend so security is handled.

Comment: Do you have make any try to use twilio video on asp.net webforms ? If yest, what was the error or the problem - if not, maybe to look for tutorials on twilion web site ?

Comment: I managed to get it running with JQuery and .NET backend. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56914667/can-i-use-twilio-video-js-sdk-2-0-in-jquery.